# Can I bind google.com to a site created in IIS 7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, bindings

I have seen binding option in the IIS 7 to bind different sites. I tried to bind a google.com to a site created in the IIS 7 but it didn't work. Can you please clarify with the concept of binding in IIS. thanks !

Comment: You are the owner of Google? Ask your employees.

Comment: I know, am not the owner of the Google otherwise I would have redirected without posting here. that's why I am asking people to clarify the binding in IIS.

Comment: So then the answer is simple: You can't. It's not your domain. And if you forge your DNS to make it "your" domain, then nobody can use the real google.com anymore.

Answer (score 1):

IIS has the ability to serve multiple sites from a single IP Address using "host headers" which means than when a request comes in to a particular domain e.g. http://google.com or http://microsoft, even if both those are pointed to the same IP address in your DNS server, IIS can detect which one the request is for and direct the request to the correct site/virtual site.

Without this, we would have run out of IPv4 addresses long ago as it basically allows hosting companies to put multiple sites on single servers with a single IP.

Of course you need to OWN the domain in order to point the DNS record to your server (!) or, for testing purpose could just hack your /etc/hosts file

Comment: typical binding for websites are in the form IP:Port:HostHeader. Can you please clarify me here. If multiple sites can host on single IP address, then in the format IP address does not change. right ? Is there any scenario to get more than one IP address in the bindings....I mean like this eg., 192.26.34.23 :80:microsoft, 192.45.36.28:80:google src:http://blogs.technet.com/b/chrad/archive/2010/01/24/understanding-iis-bindings-websites-virtual-directories-and-lastly-application-pools.aspx

Comment: I think by "Binding" you're talking about the IP's that IIS will listen on. So, say you have 3 network cards on your server, you might choose to say some sites listen on network card 1 (Or, more technically, it's IP address(es)) and others on network card 2 etc. That, however, has no real relation to your original question. I think you need to clarify your terminology and what exactly you're trying to achieve and why.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good blog post explaining the concepts of binding in IIS. http://blogs.technet.com/b/chrad/archive/2010/01/24/understanding-iis-bindings-websites-virtual-directories-and-lastly-application-pools.aspx

If you have a concrete question, then come back with that.